# Solve $y' = \frac{1}{x\cos(y) + \sin(2y)}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to solve this ODE

$$ y' = \dfrac{1}{x\cos(y) + \sin(2y)}$$

Could you give me any hints? I don't even know how to start.

Comment: Maybe to first write this equation like $x'=...$ (to eliminate that fraction).

Comment: @Cortizol With your hint the solution is straightforward.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is Ist order Linear,

$\frac{dx}{dy}-x\cos y=\sin2y $

So,

$\frac{dx}{dy}+xP(y)=Q(y)$

So, making use of general solution,

$ x = e^{-\int P(y)dy} \Big[\int Q(y)e^{\int P(y)dy}dy+C \Big]$

$   = e^{\sin y}\Big[-2e^{-\sin y}(\sin y+1) + C\Big]$

$ x = -2(\sin y +1) + C e^{\sin y}$

Answer (score 6):

We have $\sin(2y)=2\sin(y)\cos(y)$, thus we can write the equation as:
$$y'=\frac{1}{\cos(y)(x+2\sin(y))}$$
Now let $z=\sin(y)$, so that we obtain:
$$z'=y'\cos(y)=\frac{1}{x+2z}$$
Can you take it from here?

Comment: Not really sure how to take it from there. I have understood what you did, though (Is hard for me to see those changes of variable so quickly =(

Comment: @Trollkemada If you want a further *big* hint, try substitution with $u=x+2z$. As for "seeing" substitutions, it's just a matter of training your intuition and trying around a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing after georg's answer, the solution in terms of $y$ is given by 
$$y=-\sin ^{-1}\Big(  W\left(C e^{-(1+\frac{x}{2})}\right)+(1+\frac{x}{2})\Big)$$